# Spring Batch and Spring Integration. Can not configure JobListener

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I'm new in Spring. Recently I do try to make spring batch and spring integration work together. I want to have JobListener which will listen for message comes to specific channel and launch Spring Batch Job.

I found example on github(https://github.com/chrisjs/spring-batch-scaling/tree/master/message-job-launch)  and I tried to configure some way copy Spring Batch and Spring Integration together and this looks like:

```
<!--Incomming channel OneToOne-->
<int:channel id="requests-channel"/>

<!--For multiple consumers OneToMany-->
<int:publish-subscribe-channel id="reply-channel"/>

<!--Channel for file adapter-->
<int:channel id="file-adapter-reply-channel"/>

<int:channel id="statuses">
    <int:queue capacity="10"/>
</int:channel>


<int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>


<!--Intercept request-->
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="requests-channel"
                          supported-methods="PUT"
                          path="/testData/setProfileDescription"
                          reply-timeout="30000"
                          reply-channel="reply-channel">
</int-http:inbound-gateway>


<!--Sending HTTP response back to user OR either 'no reply received within timeout'-->
<bean id="profileDescriptionActivator"
      class="ru.tcsbank.service.integrations.activators.ProfileDescriptionActivator"/>

<int:service-activator ref="profileDescriptionActivator"
                       input-channel="requests-channel"
                       output-channel="reply-channel"
                       method="httpMessageActivator"/>


<!--Write profile description to file-->
<bean id="custom-file-name-generator"
      class="ru.tcsbank.service.integrations.transformers_generators.ProfilesFileAdapterNameGenerator"/>
<file:outbound-channel-adapter channel="file-adapter-reply-channel"
                               directory="file:out"
                               filename-generator="custom-file-name-generator"/>


<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" lazy-init="true" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="test_user"/>
    <property name="password" value="qwerty123"/>
</bean>


<bean id="stepScope" class="org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope">
    <property name="autoProxy" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepositoryInDB" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>


<bean id="itemProcessor" class="ru.tcsbank.service.batch_processing.CustomItemProcessor"/>

<bean id="itemReader" class="ru.tcsbank.service.batch_processing.CustomReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:fileOut/*.csv" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value=","/>
                    <property name="names" value="id,firstName,lastName"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <bean class="ru.tcsbank.service.batch_processing.ProfileDescriptionLineMapper"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="itemWriter" class="ru.tcsbank.service.batch_processing.CustomWriter"/>

<batch:job id="helloWorldJob" job-repository="jobRepositoryInDB">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>


<int:transformer input-channel="reply-channel" output-channel="file-adapter-reply-channel">
    <bean class="ru.tcsbank.service.batch_processing.FileMessageToJobRequest">
        <property name="job" ref="helloWorldJob"/>
        <property name="fileParameterName" value="input.file.name"/>
    </bean>
</int:transformer>


<bean id="jobListener" class="ru.tcsbank.service.batch_processing.CustomJobExecutionListener">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="notificationSender"/>
</bean>

<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="reply-channel"
                                 reply-channel="file-adapter-reply-channel"/>

<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>

<int:channel id="notificationsChannel"/>
<int:gateway id="notificationSender"
             service-interface="ru.tcsbank.service.batch_processing.NotificationSender"
             default-request-channel="notificationsChannel"/>
```

I expect my `helloWorldJob` run when(as I understand correctly) my `jobListener` receives message from `notificationsChannel`. But it do not work(do not receives message from `notificationsChannel`) Beyond then it throws error like:

> Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 
>   'application.notificationsChannel'.; nested exception is >org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher >has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=TEST. >Image processing job ran for: 0 minutes, 0 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you would like to achieve with all this custom code, but what I can say, that there is no subscribers for that `notificationsChannel` in your configuration. You indeed send messages to it via `notificationSender`  gateway, but you don't provide any endpoint to consume that `notificationsChannel`.

In the sample you mention in the link we have something like this:

```
<int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="notifications" destination-name="notifications"
              channel="notificationsChannel"/>
```

So, messages sent to the `notificationsChannel` are landed in the `notifications` queue on JMS broker. Your sample are leaking such a subscriber. Therefore I only can explain a reason of the exception, but definitely can't tell you what do to.

**UPDATE**

You may not use `notificationSender` in your solution. Looks like it just a result of the `CustomJobExecutionListener`. So, if you don't need to listen for job process, just remove that `CustomJobExecutionListener` and, therefore, this `notificationSender` declaration together with the `notificationsChannel` definition.

Everything else you are asking in comments is out of the scope of this SO question. Please, consider to raise those concerns in the separate SO thread.

Comment: Tnx.
First, I want to fix problem with `notificationSender` but I don't want to use `int-jms:outbound-channel-adapter ` and use stub if possible.
Second, I do have `int-http:inbound-gateway` which listen for POST HTTP requests and if request comes send request body to `file:outbound-channel-adapter` and `file:outbound-channel-adapter` store request body in folder. I want, if `int-http:inbound-gateway` intercept POST HTTP request(like it work now) I want to sent HTTP request body to `file:outbound-channel-adapter` to store in folder and trigger `helloWorldJob` pass request body as parameter.

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Got it. Thank you